# #define new macros inside the #define macro function

Tags: c, function, macros

```
#define RB3_SetHigh()            do { LATBbits.LATB3 = 1; } while(0)
#define RB3_SetLow()             do { LATBbits.LATB3 = 0; } while(0)


#define SET_ALIAS(new_name, old_name) { \
        #define new_name##_SetHigh()    old_name##_SetHigh()    \     
        #define new_name##_SetLow()     old_name##_SetLow()     \ 
        }


SET_ALIAS(MOTOR,RB3)
```

I am trying to change the prefix of an already-defined function macro. I want to rename the MACRO Function in C.

I thought I will use another MACRO Function and will use the MACRO concatenation to achieve this. But it is not allowed. There are my functions that I want to change in the code.

Comment: There is no question in your post. If your question is whether you can use a macro to define a macro, then it is answered in your post: “It is not allowed.” C 2018 6.10.3.4 says, of macro replacement, “The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one…”

Comment: Counter question to your non-question: why?